# Изменение части border'а при наведении на элемент

Tags: html, css, css3

Можно ли как-то изменить часть border'а при наведении на элемент. Вот так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал делать так:

```css
.nav-menu {
  margin-top: 33px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ececec;
}

nav a {
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ececec;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #f03c3c;
  padding-top: 25px;
  border-top: 1px solid #f03c3c;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-menu">
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Blog</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конкретно бордером не получится без доп. обертки, но можно сделать с помощью псевдоэлемента.

```css
.nav-menu {
  margin-top: 33px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ececec;
}

nav a {
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ececec;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #f03c3c;
}

nav a:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -34px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #f03c3c;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-menu">
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Blog</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```